# wp_redirect not working from shortcode function

Tags: wp-redirect

Whenever I use `wp_redirect(plugins_url('account/login'));` in a shortcode function I get the following error:

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by ...
```

Is there any way to redirect from there? My guess would to echo some Javascript that does the redirect from me, but I was wondering whether there would be a server-side implementation of this.

Comment: check in your functions.php, did you have closing `?>` tag at the end ? if yes remove it and try again

Comment: @wordpresser there are no closing `?>` in any of my plugin files

Comment: You are most likely hooking it too late. How do you implement it?

Comment: where are you trying to use it? you can't send headers after content output has started.

Comment: I'm indeed using it from within a shortcode function. Any way to redirect from there?

Comment: Only, when using Javascript. `window.location.href = '/your-link';`. But that is no nice solution. It's better to do it from somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Why does it need to be a Shortcode? Looks like a [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

You're already inserting the shortcode manually in the edit screen. Use a Custom Field instead and hook earlier where you can *actually do the redirect*.

[image]

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', function(){
    global $post;
    $redirect = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'redirect', true );
    if( $redirect )
    {
        wp_redirect( admin_url( 'profile.php' ) );
        exit;
    }
});
```

Comment: Also, redirecting to `plugins_url('account/login')` doesn't sound like a good idea...

Answer (score 0):

To redirect to another page you need to set an http header. To set an header it has to be the first thing that is output to the browser.

You are trying to set an header when something already has been output to the browser, that's why you get the warning and the redirect doesn't work.

You need to change your implementation so that the redirect is triggered before anything got output. So you should hook it to `init` or any other action that happens before output.

This can also happen due to another plugin which incorrectly outputs something when it shouldn't.